# Getting Highest Resolution from a Camera in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, resolution, pixel

I have an openCV/hardware problem- I am using a web camera that has a resolution of 1600x1200.

I need roughly 5x-10x that resolution for a project I am working on . I have looked on the market and I can't seem to find any good web cameras with higher than 1080P resolution.

However, you often see that even cell phones are using larger resolution for their pictures.

Often times the resolution of the camera is lower using video and higher when using a still image.

With openCV you can take images (right?), so how can I increase my resolution within opencv without using interpolation resizing methods?

Or where can I get a really fantastic web camera?! thanks!

Comment: Newer high end smartphones record videos with 4K resolution. To get higher you have to use interpolation. To make this better you could use a DSLR with a fast burst mode.